# Do I need a SMTP server in using the PHP's mail() function

Tags: php, smtp

Do I need a SMTP server in using the PHP's mail() function?

p.s. I am on a share hosting account, so I cannot install a SMTP server and they don't provide that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP's mail() function doesn't need SMTP. It uses a program called **sendmail** which is generally available on Unix/Linux platforms by default and most web hosts provides this facility for no extra charge.

Answer (score 1):

PHP on Linux servers relies on a local MTA for the mail() function.

PHP on Windows can be configured to use whatever SMTP server you like.

PEAR::Mail allows you to set which SMTP server you want to use.
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.intro.php

With the first parameter as 'smtp', the second param accepts details.
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

Comment: ORLY? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php That page only mentions sendmail.